# why should we use stdout=PIPE in subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, process, command, pipe

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p = Popen("ls -l",shell=True,stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
(out,err) = p.communicate()
print(out, err)
```

In above Popen call, if I remove `stdout=PIPE`, I am getting newline after every listing by `ls -l` in output. But if use `stdout=PIPE`, I get `\n` displayed, rather than newline, as below

```
b'total 67092\n-rw-r--r--  1 root root      171 May 27 09:08 new.py\n-rw-r--r--  1   
    root root       74 May 12 18:14 abcd.conf\n-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     5948 May 13 13:21 abxyz.sh\ndrwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 May 13
12:39 log\ndrwxrwxrwx  3 root root     4096 May 14 16:02
newpy\n-rw-r--r--  1 root root      134 May 27 10:13
pipe.py\n-rw-r--r--  1 root root      155 May 27 10:07
proc.py\ndrwxrwxrwx  3 root root     4096 May 14 14:29 py\ndrwxr-xr-x
16 1000 1000\n' b''
```

How does `PIPE` exactly works in case of `subprocess.Popen`? Why do we need it? I got proper output without using it also? Are we using this for getting both stderr, stdout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `print()` call to see the difference.

When you do not pipe the `ls` output to Python, it is instead displayed on your terminal directly; it's output goes to your terminal. If you pipe it to Python, you get to see the whole contents as bytes, including newline bytes (represented as `\n`).

Decode the results if you want the newlines to be printed literally:

```
print(out.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Ohh. I saw it without print. It is directly displaying on my screen. I thought I was printing it. What happens when I use in case of `stdin` without PIPE?

Comment: Also after using `stdout=PIPE`, it is not displaying stderr also on screen, Why? shouldn't it only PIPE stdout and display stderr.

Comment: `ls` writes to the `stdout` filehandle, which when you don't pipe is directly connected to your terminal. When you do pipe it into Python, you are capturing anything `ls` writes to it. `ls` is *not* writing anything to `stderr`. When you use `PIPE` for `stderr`, you see that your `err` variable is empty (`b''` is an empty bytes value).

Comment: If I don't use `stderr=PIPE` in Popen and `print(err)`, I get `None` in output for `err`. My question was why this `None` not getting displayed directly on screen. Because it was getting displayed with no PIPE for stdout and stderr.

Comment: You didn't capture stderr, so python returns None because a value is required. ls did not print None; None is a Python value signifying an empty value.